# How to accept PIN as an authentication method for a ucma application without the workflow sdk?

Tags: lync, lync-2010, ucma

Would like to see maybe a sample implementation in a ucma bot that authenticates a caller with a pin just with the use a the core ucma api (without using the workflow sdk)

I tried hooking it up with the `ToneReceived` event of the `ToneController` but its only able to know the first digit of the series of numbers im trying to press on the dialer.

Anyone seen such implementation before? please point me to it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're 99% of the way there. The `ToneReceived` event will only listen for one tone at a time. Therefore, for a multiple number, the event will fire multiple times and you will need to add each tone as it's received into a collection or array, then decide when to unregister the event (maybe after 4 tones have been entered) and then evaluate the array for a correct PIN.

There's a QuickStart sample included in the SDK which should be on your machine at:

`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft UCMA 3.0\SDK\Core\Sample Applications\QuickStarts\AudioVideoCall\ToneController`

but to be honest, it sounds like you've got most of the UCMA-specific stuff already working.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Tom, yes saw that sample already. catching the event on multiple fires is the only way atm? there must be a better way for that, in my opinion..